# How to get component located in a specific gridx, gridy from a JPanel with GridBagLayout layout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I have a jpanel with gridbaglayout layout, in it i have several jtextfields, several jlabels, several jbuttons which get added dynamically. Therefore I cannot know their specific orders, hence cannot use panel.getComponent(count). I looked in the api if there is something like getGridx(int x) or getGridy(int y). Didn't find. Is there anything similar to those methods?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution might be to use [`GridBagLayout#getConstraints(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints%28java.awt.Component%29) and simply loop through all the components until you find one that matches the required grid position...

```
Component match = null;
GridBagLayout layout = ...
for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = layout.getConstraints(comp);
    if (gbc.gridx = x && gbc.gridy = y) {
        match = comp;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this case in my code many times, and consuming too much loops. Which is not favourable. I've edited my question.  "getGridx(int x) or getGridy(int y)" instead of getGridx(), getGridy(). I.e. I need to put those x and y myself.

Comment: The other solution would be to create some kind of `Map`(s) that you could do reverse looks with.  Basically when you add a component, record it's x/y position into the `Map`(s) then use this to do your lookups...Based on your comments, I would suggest you will end up with a least 3 `Map`s, `mapX`, `mapY`, `maxXY`....